# Set Div Behind Background Image

Tags: css, html, background-image, z-index

I ave a header with a background image and a page container in the body of my page

The HTML:

```
<header>
<nav>Item1-Item2</nav>
</header>

<div class="container">
Content
</div>
```

The css:

```
header{
background: url(images/header.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: 100% 110%;
position: relative;
z-index: 99999;
}
```

I would liek to set the content of the container to be under the header, so the the header and it's background image overlaps over the top of the page container.

The code above doesn't work, the container seems to be behind but, the background image does not overlap and show over the content area top.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `header { position: absolute; }` ?

Comment: Set `position:absolute;` on the header.

Comment: @Brian this still has the background image of the header showing up behind the div container. I need the background image to overlap and be over the top of the container, which is why I set the z-index as above, but it isn't working

Comment: C-link Nepal's answer should do the trick

Comment: @Brian I provided an example in the edit above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set`.container`'s  `top` position negatively to move it upwards however as much you want the `header` to overlap. Because of the z-index on `header`, `page-wrap` will naturally fall beneath it.

```
.container {
  padding-bottom: 240px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background: url('images/OVbg2.png') no-repeat left bottom, url('images/OVbg3.png') no-repeat left top;
  background-size: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
}
```

You may want to save it as a transparent png for the overlap to not include the blue background

Comment: This doesn't change the result, yes the page wrap is behind the header, but I want the peel background image of the header to show over the top of the page wrap, it still shows up behind, I want the peel background image to be show over the overlap , not under

Comment: It isnt showing up behind it. Read the last sentence of my answer because I addressed that issue too

Comment: @Tester replace the header image with this http://oi62.tinypic.com/1zw0qhh.jpg ( a transparent png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JSFiddle of what i BELIEVE you are trying to do...correct me if I'm wrong:

http://jsfiddle.net/t2cjmwtd/

Make sure you have the header set as `position: fixed` and the `.container` needs to be `position: relative` in order for you to be able to set a `z-index` on it as well.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue of the background image, which is the real problem

Answer (score 0):

Updated the Answer as per your Edit:

As per the example site, all they are doing to override Header div is: providing margin in "-" negative value like "margin-top: -30px;"

Add "`position:absolute`" to the "`header`"

Here is the sample code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="main-container">
    <header>
        <nav>Item1-Item2</nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">Content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
    background: #ffff00 url(http://cbbnideas.com/orchard/wp-content/themes/Orchard/images/header.jpg) no-repeat;
    min-height: 200px;
    height: 40%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}
.container {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 7px rgba(17, 17, 17, .5);
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
```

### Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2az1hzne/5/

Comment: The peel image in the header still isn't overlapping over the white container, it's separated, I've been trying for soo long to get this to work.

Comment: Its overlapping.. if you are talking about the blue color below "Orange Peel" image, then its part of the image only... you need to fix the image to make it transparent. Otherwise if you see the Orange Peel image box "Header" is overlapping the "Container" as the "content" is hiding behind the Image.

Comment: Checkout this updated fiddle to get an idea of overlapping boxes : http://jsfiddle.net/2az1hzne/4/